# Error: "Exception thrown: write access violation. text was 0x

Tags: c++, exception, access-violation

I need to write a function which capitalizes every letter from the beginning of a word in a char (ie `"hello. this is a test"` into `"Hello. This Is A Test"`). My teacher gave me the header of the function I need to use, as well as the return statement from it.

When I run it, it shows me the error "write access violation", and I really don't understand why. I've looked a lot on the Internet, but couldn't find anything that looked like my scenario.

This is what my teacher asks:

> Implement the toTitleCase (char * text) method that converts received text to Title Case format
>
> - all words start with a capital letter
> - ex: "hello. this is a test" becomes "Hello. This Is A Test"

Also, I am testing this with a Google Test in VS 2019 for C++, and the testing function is:

```
TEST(TestTitleCase, RightTest) {
    char* text = "hello. this is a test";
    char* newText = toTitleCase(text);
    ASSERT_TRUE(newText != nullptr);
    EXPECT_EQ(strcmp(newText, "Hello. This Is A Test"), 0);
}
```

And this is what I wrote:

```
char* toTitleCase(char* text) {

    text[0] = text[0] - 32;  //the error is here
    for (int i = 1; i < strlen(text); i++)
        if ((text[i] != ' ') && (text[i - 1] == ' '))
            text[i] = text[i] - 'a' + 'A';  //when I comment the first line I also get an error here
    cout << text;
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: This line `char* text = "hello. this is a test";` should be giving you a compiler diagnostic.  Try setting / increasing the compiler warning level.

Comment: Is the `TEST` function in a C program? It's not legal C++.

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish by subtracting 32 from `text[0]`? Why only `text[0]`? Do you really need to return `nullptr` from this function? Are you expected to modify the string in place, if so why return a `char *` at all? Are you expected to create a new `char` string, and leave the original one untouched? On the very first iteration of the `for` loop, with `i` at its initially value of 0, do you realize that `text[i-1] == '  '` ends up comparing `text[-1]` with a space? Do you think that makes sense? Your question is unclear, and there are multiple bugs here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik my guess from the problem the user is trying to solve is that they are thinking of `text[0] - 32` like an ascii value shift.

Comment: Your function is supposed to return a string, not print it and return a null pointer. It also needs to create a new string rather than modify the input.

Comment: first iteration: `text[i - 1]` tries to acces `text[ -1]`.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers like `32`. Use `' '` if you want a space character.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the TEST function(which no, it is not in C, it s in C++), nor the header or type of the toTitleCase function, and nor the return nullptr at the end of the function. I am subtracting 32 from text[0] at the beginning in order to be able to create the if condition regarding if the previous space is or not a "space" character, starting from character text[1]. Yes, I had a mistake in my code, since my "i" was starting from 0 and not 1 as it should had, but I fixed it and I still get that warning on the "text[0] = text[0] -32" line

Comment: @TedLyngmo Unfortunately that doesn't solve it

Comment: @Tania No, not using magic number doesn't solve this problem. If it's C++, the `TEST` function should not even compile. If I try the line `char* text = "hello. this is a test";` in VS2019 I get: `Error C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [22]' to 'char *'`

Comment: maybe you misunderstood the `TEST`. It assersts that `toTitleCase` does **not** return a `nullptr`. I guess only if something went wrong you are supposed to return a `nullptr`. If you do return a `nullptr` you will fail the `TEST`

Comment: @TedLyngmo — `TEST` is a macro in the testing framework.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, but my comment was about the invalid C++ code inside the test.

Answer (score 1):

In `TEST()`, you have `text` pointing at a string literal <sup>1</sup>, which is stored in read-only memory. You are passing `text` to `toTitleCase()`.

<sup>1: however, you appear to be using a C++11 compiler, due to your use of `nullptr`, and it is illegal in C++11 and later to assign a narrow string literal to a non-const `char*` pointer, as you have shown.</sup>

In `toTitleCase()`, you are trying to modify the contents of the string pointed at by the `text` parameter. But `text` is pointing at a read-only string literal, hence the access violation.

To fix the error, you can change this line:

```cpp
char* text = "hello. this is a test";
```

To this instead:

```cpp
char text[] = "hello. this is a test";
```

This creates a *writable copy* of the string literal's data.

---

That being said, you should be using `std::string` instead of `char*`, if possible, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

...

TEST(TestTitleCase, RightTest)
{
    string text = "hello. this is a test";
    string newText = toTitleCase(text);
    EXPECT_EQ(newText, "Hello. This Is A Test");
}

char upperCase(char c)
{
    return static_cast<char>(toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
}

string toTitleCase(string text)
{
    text[0] = upperCase(text[0]);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < text.size(); i++) {
        if ((text[i] != ' ') && (text[i - 1] == ' '))
            text[i] = upperCase(text[i]);
    }
    cout << text;
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The major problem though is the fact that my teacher strictly forbid us to change the function's header or the TEST function. I've tried the code as you said, with char text[] and the other alterations, and it works perfectly. However, I will not get any points if I upload this method, since I replaced the initial char* text.

Comment: @Tania the problem is in `TEST()`, not in `toTitleCase()`. To fix this error by changing only `toTitleCase()`, you would have to make `toTitleCase()` allocate a writable copy of `text` before modifying it. But that creates a memory leak if `TEST()` can't be changed to free the copy, unless `toTitleCase()` uses a global/static `char[]` buffer. Your teacher gave you bad code to work with.